# Tensorflow Faster R-CNN with Resnet-50 (v1) Object Detection API Results Only One Bounding Box on Per Image

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api, faster-rcnn

**Environment:**

- Google Colaboratory.
- TPU.

**Dataset:**

- Custom Dataset.
- Number of classes=1

**Results:**

[image]

**Expected Results:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While running the inference code change:

```
'max_boxes_to_draw=5'    #max number of bounding boxes in the image
```

You will get specified number of bounding boxes on image.